# Java moving last array element into first

Tags: java, arrays

I need to move the java array last element into first .

```
int[] ar = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

input is like `1 2 3 4 5`

output should be like `5 1 2 3 4`

please provide the code

i have tried the below code

```
int temp ;

         for(int i = 0; i<ar.length -1; i++){

             temp = ar[i];
             ar[i] = ar[i+1];
             ar[i+1] = temp;

         }
```

But it is giving output as 23451

Comment: Please show what you have so far. For more information, see what is [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is a blatant coding request.

Comment: i have added the code whatever i tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] ar = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int[] result = new int[ar.length];
    System.arraycopy(ar, 0, result, 1, ar.length - 1);
    result[0] = ar[ar.length - 1];
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
}
```